# Overriding dict.update() method in subclass to prevent overwriting dict keys

Tags: python, dictionary

Earlier today, I read the question "[Raise error if python dict comprehension overwrites a key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30238783/raise-error-if-python-dict-comprehension-overwrites-a-key)" and decided to try my hand at an answer.  The method that naturally occurred to me was to subclass `dict` for this.  However, I got stuck on my answer, and now I'm obsessed with getting this worked out for myself.

**Notes:**

- No - I do not plan on turning in the answer to this question as an answer to the other question.
- This is purely an intellectual exercise for me at this point.  As a practical matter, I would almost certainly use a `namedtuple` or a regular dictionary wherever I have a requirement for something like this.

## My (not quite working) Solution:

```
class DuplicateKeyError(KeyError):
    pass



class UniqueKeyDict(dict):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.update(*args, **kwargs)


    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        if key in self:  # Validate key doesn't already exist.
            raise DuplicateKeyError('Key \'{}\' already exists with value \'{}\'.'.format(key, self[key]))
        super().__setitem__(key, value)


    def update(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if args:
            if len(args) > 1:
                raise TypeError('Update expected at most 1 arg.  Got {}.'.format(len(args)))
            else:
                try:
                    for k, v in args[0]:
                        self.__setitem__(k, v)
                except ValueError:
                    pass

        for k in kwargs:
            self.__setitem__(k, kwargs[k])
```

## My Tests and Expected Results

```
>>> ukd = UniqueKeyDict((k, int(v)) for k, v in ('a1', 'b2', 'c3', 'd4'))  # Should succeed.
>>> ukd['e'] = 5  # Should succeed.
>>> print(ukd)
{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, d: 4, 'e': 5}
>>> ukd['a'] = 5  # Should fail.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 8, in __setitem__
__main__.DuplicateKeyError: Key 'a' already exists with value '1'.
>>> ukd.update({'a': 5})  # Should fail.
>>> ukd = UniqueKeyDict((k, v) for k, v in ('a1', 'b2', 'c3', 'd4', 'a5'))  # Should fail.
>>>
```

I'm certain the issue is in my `update()` method, but I'm not able to determine just what I'm doing wrong.

Below is the original version of my `update()` method.  This version fails as expected on duplicates when calling `my_dict.update({k: v})` for a key/value pair already in the dict, but does not fail when including a duplicate key while creating the original dict, due to the fact that converting the args to a `dict` results in default behavior for a dictionary, i.e., overwriting the duplicate key.

```
def update(self, *args, **kwargs):
    for k, v in dict(*args, **kwargs).items():
        self.__setitem__(k, v)
```

Comment: If at most one positional argument is allowed, use `update(self, arg=None, **kwargs)` instead of allowing an arbitrary number of arguments.

Comment: O/t, but shouldn't `DuplicateKeyError` subclass `KeyError`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe - I thought of that a little while ago and will make the update.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Note that, per the documentation:

- [`dict.update`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.update) takes a single `other` parameter, *"either another dictionary object or an iterable of key/value pairs"* (I've used [`collections.Mapping`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Mapping) to test for this) and *"If keyword arguments are specified, the dictionary is then updated with those key/value pairs"*; and
- [`dict()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict) takes a single `Mapping` or `Iterable` along with optional `**kwargs` (the same as `update` accepts...).

This is not quite the interface you have implemented, which is leading to some issues. I would have implemented this as follows:

```
from collections import Mapping


class DuplicateKeyError(KeyError):
    pass


class UniqueKeyDict(dict):

    def __init__(self, other=None, **kwargs):
        super().__init__()
        self.update(other, **kwargs)

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        if key in self:
            msg = 'key {!r} already exists with value {!r}'
            raise DuplicateKeyError(msg.format(key, self[key]))
        super().__setitem__(key, value)

    def update(self, other=None, **kwargs):
        if other is not None:
            for k, v in other.items() if isinstance(other, Mapping) else other:
                self[k] = v
        for k, v in kwargs.items():
            self[k] = v
```

In use:

```
>>> UniqueKeyDict((k, v) for k, v in ('a1', 'b2', 'c3', 'd4'))
{'c': '3', 'd': '4', 'a': '1', 'b': '2'}
>>> UniqueKeyDict((k, v) for k, v in ('a1', 'b2', 'c3', 'a4'))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#8>", line 1, in <module>
    UniqueKeyDict((k, v) for k, v in ('a1', 'b2', 'c3', 'a4'))
  File "<pyshell#7>", line 5, in __init__
    self.update(other, **kwargs)
  File "<pyshell#7>", line 15, in update
    self[k] = v
  File "<pyshell#7>", line 10, in __setitem__
    raise DuplicateKeyError(msg.format(key, self[key]))
DuplicateKeyError: "key 'a' already exists with value '1'"
```

and:

```
>>> ukd = UniqueKeyDict((k, v) for k, v in ('a1', 'b2', 'c3', 'd4'))
>>> ukd.update((k, v) for k, v in ('e5', 'f6'))  # single Iterable
>>> ukd.update({'h': 8}, g='7')  # single Mapping plus keyword args
>>> ukd
{'e': '5', 'f': '6', 'a': '1', 'd': '4', 'c': '3', 'h': 8, 'b': '2', 'g': '7'}
```

If you ever end up using this, I'd be inclined to give it a different `__repr__` to avoid confusion!

Comment: I haven't had the opportunity to test your answer (or any of the others yet), but a quick question about your implementation: Any particular reason you chose to use `Iterable` instead of `abc.Iterable`, which would've been my normal choice if I'd've thought to go down this path?  Also, the point about the `__repr__` is a good one.  I still wouldn't ordinarily use it, but I've thought of a few use cases for it.  Not sure if they would warrant the added complexity, however.

Comment: @DougR. assuming you mean `collections.abc.Iterable` (there is no `Iterable` in [`abc`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html)) it's an alias for the same thing: *"Changed in version 3.3: Moved Collections Abstract Base Classes to the `collections.abc` module. For backwards compatibility, they continue to be visible in this module as well."*

Comment: **Sigh** - I've got to be more precise.  You're absolutely correct - I did mean `collections.abc.Iterable`.  Thanks for the info - I should've looked it up myself.  I will definitely take a look and play with some code tonight.

Comment: Hmm.  `ukd.update({'a', 5})` still fails.  I'm getting the error `ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack`.  It should fail, but with a `DuplicateKeyError`.  I also tried `ukd.update({'f': 6})`, which should have succeeded, but got the same error.

Comment: @DougR. edited - `Mapping`s are `Iterable` but not necessarily vice versa, so I've switched the test in `update` around, it should work fine now

Comment: Thank you for the education in Iterables and Mappings.  It's exercises like this that make me realize just how much I still have to learn.  When I have time, I'll update the question to include the final solution.

Comment: @DougR. Me too! Don't update the question - if you think there is something to be added, write your own answer.

Comment: Only thing to add would be an `overwrite` method (because if you actually use this, you know you're going to want to at some point...), a `__repr__`, and documentation of the code.  When I finally get something like this hammered out, I like to feel like I've actually completed it.

Comment: @DougR. seems like a good idea to me - I've just realised that `UniqueKeyDict()` will fail, so have updated to make `other` default to `None`.

Comment: I woke up sometime last night wondering what would happen if I did that, but hadn't actually tested it yet.

Answer (score 11):

It's interesting that simply overriding `__setitem__` is not enough to change the behavior of `update` in `dict`. I would have expected that `dict` would use its `__setitem__` method when it's being updated using `update`. In all cases, I think it's better to implement `collections.MutableMapping` to achieve the desired result without touching `update`:

```
import collections

class UniqueKeyDict(collections.MutableMapping, dict):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self._dict = dict(*args, **kwargs)

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self._dict[key]

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        if key in self:
            raise DuplicateKeyError("Key '{}' already exists with value '{}'.".format(key, self[key]))
        self._dict[key] = value

    def __delitem__(self, key):
        del self._dict[key]

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self._dict)

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self._dict)
```

Edit: included `dict` as base class to satisfy the `isinstance(x, dict)` check.

Comment: Good use of the included ABCs, but this way you have to implement six methods instead of three and (in case it's important) `isinstance(UniqueKeyDict(), dict)` will be `False` (although of course people should be using `isinstance(..., collections.Mapping)`!)

Comment: That was counterintuitive to me as well, when I wrote my first iteration of `UniqueKeyDict` (not the best name, but the best I could come up with on short notice).  Also, the reason I subclass `dict` is so that `isinstance(UniqueKeyDict(), dict)` will be `True`, as well as the fact that I won't have to reimplement all the various methods.

Comment: Well, we can always include dict in the base classes to satisfy the `isinstance` check without affecting the class' behavior

Comment: And about the number of methods to implement, although more but fairly simple.

Comment: Yes, in LOC terms it's only two longer than mine (ignoring whitespace and the fact that I've split the `raise` over two lines).

Comment: That works really well. If you  raise an exception from `__delitem__` it makes the existing key protected.

Comment: This is a better answer than the accepted one.  Why write a contrived method, when you can implement the abstract methods and get the desired behaviour for free

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure this is the problem but I just noticed that you are treating your `args` in the `update` method as a list of pairs:

```
for k, v in args[0]
```

while you are actually supplying a dictionary:

```
ukd.update({'a': 5})
```

Have you tried this:

```
try:
    for k, v in args[0].iteritems():
        self.__setitem__(k, v)
except ValueError:
    pass
```

EDIT: Probably this error went unnoticed because you are `except`ing a `ValueError`, which is what treating a dictionary as a list of pairs will raise.

Comment: You're absolutely correct about the error I was making, but that ended up not being the actual issue.  Thanks for the catch!

Answer (score 2):

I was able to achieve the goal with the following code:

```
class UniqueKeyDict(dict):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.update(*args, **kwargs)

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        if self.has_key(key):
            raise DuplicateKeyError("%s is already in dict" % key)
        dict.__setitem__(self, key, value)

    def update(self, *args, **kwargs):
        for d in list(args) + [kwargs]:
            for k,v in d.iteritems():
                self[k]=v
```

Comment: Hmm.  `ukd.update({'a', 5})` is now the only test that fails.  I'm getting the error `ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack`.  It should fail, but with a `DuplicateKeyError`.  I also tried `ukd.update({'f': 6})`, which should **not** have generated an error, but got the same error.

Comment: Which Python version are you using? I used the following and it worked nicely: ``i = UniqueKeyDict({1:1, 2:2, 3:3})
    
    i.update({'a':1})
    i.update({'a':2})``

Comment: Python 3.  I assume from the `d.iteritems()` that you're using Python 2?  When I moved your approach into 3, the only difference I had is that I split the `for` into two parts, one to process `args` and one to process `kwargs`.  When I use it as-is in Python3 just changing `d.iteritems()` to `d.items()`, then everything goes boom.

Comment: Are you sure that you are using the values inside args? args is a tuple of values; in this case, I am expecting that args is a tuple of dictionaries. Therefore, I iterate over the dictionaries inside args (the first for loop in the solution) and before that (the second for loop) the tuples (key,value).

Answer (score 2):

This interesting question is a bit older and has already some solid answers (my favourite is the one from [sirfz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3572366/sirfz)). Nevertheless, I would like to propose yet another one. You could use the `dict`-wrapper [UserDict](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html?highlight=userdict#collections.UserDict). If I'm not mistaken, this should do the job you were looking for:

```
from collections import UserDict

class DuplicateKeyError(KeyError):
    pass

class UniqueKeyDict(UserDict):

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        if key in self:
            raise DuplicateKeyError(f"Key '{key}' already exists with value '{self[key]}'")
        self.data[key] = value
```

As with the usage of `collections.abc.MutableMapping` the `update` method gets modified implicitly. But in contrast, you *only* have to (re)define the `__setitem__` method. Since your modification is rather minor, the use of `UserDict` seems like an appropriate approach to me.

An instance of this class is not an instance of `dict`, but it is an instance of `collections.abc.Mapping`, which should be used for testing for `dict`-likeness.

Answer (score 1):

Why not do something along the lines inspired by MultiKeyDict using setdefault? This leaves the update method as a way to override the currently stored values, breaking, I know, the intent that d[k] = v == d.update({k, v}). In my application the override was useful. So before flagging this as not answering the OP question, please consider this answer might be useful for someone else.

```
class DuplicateKeyError(KeyError):
    """File exception rasised by UniqueKeyDict"""
    def __init__(self, key, value):
        msg = 'key {!r} already exists with value {!r}'.format(key, value)
        super(DuplicateKeyError, self).__init__(msg)


class UniqueKeyDict(dict):
    """Subclass of dict that raises a DuplicateKeyError exception"""
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        if key in self:
            raise DuplicateKeyError(key, self[key])
        self.setdefault(key, value)


class MultiKeyDict(dict):
    """Subclass of dict that supports multiple values per key"""
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        self.setdefault(key, []).append(value)
```

Rather new to python so flame on, probably deserve it...

Answer (score 0):

According to the given answers and `help(dict.update)` I did `force_update` method. I will appreciate it if you will post in comments a real python code of `dict.update` method (I found only [`C` source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Objects/dictobject.c)).

```
class UniqueKeyDict(UserDict):
    """
    Disable key overwriting if already exists
    """

    def __setitem__(self, key=None, value=None, **kwargs):
        if (key in self  # Different options to override key (just a fun)
                and not (isinstance(value, Iterable) and len(value) == 3 and self[key] in value and value[-1] is True)
                and not (isinstance(value, Iterable) and len(value) == 2 and value[-1] == '--force')):
            raise DuplicateKeyError(f"Key '{key}' already exists with value '{self[key]}'")
        self.data[key] = value

    def force_update(self, *a, **kw) -> None:
        """
        See help({}.update)
        """
        a = a[0] if len(a) == 1 else None  # *a is always tuple
        if a and hasattr(a, 'keys'):
            for k in a:
                self.pop(k, None)
                self[k] = a[k]
        elif a:
            for k, v in a:
                self.pop(k, None)
                self[k] = v
        for k in kw:
            self.pop(k, None)
            self[k] = kw[k]


# Check it, it should cover all the cases with regular dict.update method
du = UniqueKeyDict()
du['e'] = 3
du.force_update({'q': 1, 'qq': 2, 'qqq': 3})
du.update({'q': 1, 'qq': 2, 'qqq': 3})  # Error
du.force_update({'q': 1, 'qq': 2, 'qqq': 3})  # No error
du.force_update({})
du.force_update([])
du.force_update(w=2, ww=22, www=222)
du.force_update([[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8]])
```

Answer (score 0):

merge 2 dicts that might have duplicate keys, so prefer cd1

```
def mergeDictsWithPreference(cd1, cd2):
    cMerge = cd2.copy()
    # cd2 is 'not preferred' in dupe key case
    for c1 in cd1:
        cMerge[c1] = cd1[c1]
    return cMerge
```